# Unity UI "Toggle" on off mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my application, I used the toggle for a bool type input. I successfully post data into storage, but when I want to display the data toogle is not responding.

Hello, 
In my application, I used the toggle for a bool type input. I successfully post data into storage, but when I want to display the data toogle is not responding.

Here is my code for saving the data.

```
if(pregnancyToggle.isOn){
        form.AddField("pregnancy", "1");
    }else{
        form.AddField("pregnancy", "0");
    }
```

Here is how I'm fetching the data from db.

```
if(www.text.Split('\t')[5]=="1"){
            pregnancyToggle.onValueChanged.Invoke(true);
        }
        else
        {
           pregnancyToggle.isOn = false;
        }
```

I want to set Toggle active (tik) if parsing value is "1"
How can I do this?
[UI of toggle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQSeF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simplifying your setting of "isOn"

```
pregnancyToggle.isOn = ( www.text.Split('\t')[5]=="1");
```

Or, in your original code

```
if( www.text.Split('\t')[5]=="1")
{
    pregnancyToggle.isOn = true;
}
else
{
    pregnancyToggle.isOn = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. sometimes ago i tried with this method but it was not working :P but now it's working fine :D